# Calendar events - can they be sent at different times?

Tags: email, calendar, notifications

Can I send a calendar event to two different people at two different times?  For example, once the event is created in the calendar, I would like an email notification to one person, on the day of the event, I would like it to go to another person?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:
OOTB -> No.
Workflow -> Yes.

The workflow can start on item-creation, send the mail to the first person, will be set on-hold-until-date (or for X weeks/days/hours) and send the mail to the second person.
You can check [this link (docs.microsoft.com)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo) for further information.

Within this documentation you will get a direction on how to create workflows with SharePoint Designer.